# TypeORM CLI doesn't print any output when I run migration commands

Tags: node.js, typescript, database-migration, typeorm, ts-node

I created a TypeORM-based project intended for running migrations scripts only; I'm using the TypeORM CLI to `run`, `show` or `revert` them, but not getting any output when do it.

The only case in which I'm getting output is when I run `typeorm migration:create` or `npm run migration:create`, but in the other cases the output is the same as the following:

This is the content of my `package.json` so that you can see the `scripts` and dependencies I'm using:

```
{
   "name": "bgt-data-import",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "BGT Data Import",
   "devDependencies": {
      "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
      "@types/node": "^9.6.5",
      "typescript": "^3.9.6"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "aws-sdk": "^2.709.0",
      "axios": "^0.19.2",
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
      "npm": "^6.14.5",
      "pg": "^7.3.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "typeorm": "0.2.25"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
      "typeorm": "node -r ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
      "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate --config ./ormconfig.json --name",
      "migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run --config ./ormconfig.json",
      "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm migration:revert --config ./ormconfig.json",
      "migration:show": "npm run typeorm migration:show --config ./ormconfig.json"
   }
}
```

And this one is the `ormconfig.json` content:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5656,
  "username": "bgt_admin",
  "password": "jnppem",
  "database": "bgt",
  "synchronize": false,
  "logging": true,
  "maxQueryExecutionTime": 100000,
  "migrationsTableName": "data_import_migrations",
  "entities": [
    "src/entity/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "src/migration/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "subscribers": [
    "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

[See the result of run `npm run migration:show`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcWRe.png)

I have the following packages installed, both locally and globally:

- TypeScript: `v3.9.6` (same version locally and globally)
- ts-node: `v8.10.2` (same version locally and globally)
- TypeORM: `v0.2.25` (same version locally and globally)

Also, I have NodeJS(`v14.5.0`) and NPM(`v6.14.5`) running on Ubuntu 18.04.

What could be the reason why I'm not getting any output when I run `typeorm migration:[run|show|revert]`?

Comment: Please add `ormconfig.json` file as well.

Comment: @이준형 Added to the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why this issue was happening it’s due to ‘pg’ library in my  ‘package.json’ isn’t compatible with Postgres’ version I’ve installed.

Once I installed the newest ‘pg’ library version in my project, the issue is no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks, I spent around 4hrs to figure out the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. In my case pg was correct version but the other person was using Node 14 vs Node 12 so it was just silently crashing somewhere

Comment: I'm glad this has helped you @AvinashMaurya